# Adding "reply-to" in the email

Tags: email, woocommerce-offtopic

So, I am trying to add "reply-to" in the order email using the `billing_email`

Here is what I have so far but the code is not written well and I am not sure how to change it.

Here is the original:

```
 public function send( $to, $subject, $message, $headers = "Content-Type: text/html\r\n", $attachments = "" ) {
    $email = new WC_Email();
    $email->send( $to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments );
}
```

Then I edited to the following:

```
public function send( $to, $subject, $message, $attachments = "", $order ) {
    $headers = array( "Reply-To:  <?php echo $order->billing_email; ?>" );
    $email = new WC_Email();
    $email->send( $to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments );
}
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what the `WC_Email` class does exactly, but if the `$headers` argument is an array of headers, then you're almost there. To interpolate a variable value into a string in PHP you don't have to do the `<?php ...` stuff because it'll be rendered as is. Instead, you can use:

```
$headers = array( "Reply-To: {$order->billing_email}" );
```

Or:

```
$headers = array( 'Reply-To: ' . $order->billing_email );
```

Or:

```
$headers = array( sprintf( 'Reply-To: %s', $order->billing_email ) );
```

Also, if the billing e-mail address is user input, don't forget to validate it with `is_email()` and/or sanitize it with `sanitize_email()`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: It looks like `$headers` *asks* for a string - see [WC_Email source](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Email.html#445-469) – but then passes whatever you give it, without alteration, to  [wp_mail](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail) (that can accept a string or array.)

Comment: Yeah, `wp_mail()` takes both strings an arrays for headers so it should be fine. Otherwise just implode with `\r\n` and pass as a string.